# problem with substring in mysql

Tags: mysql, substring

I have simple EAV like database which has 3 tables: products, attributes, attribute_values.

I am using below code to find all products that have attribute 'length' and then I am using substring function to get rid of 'inch' and after that I am using between to get all products that have 'length' between 0 and 5.

```
SELECT products.name,products.id
FROM products
JOIN attribute_value_product on products.id = attribute_value_product.product_id
JOIN attribute_values on attribute_value_product.attribute_value_id = attribute_values.id
JOIN attributes on attribute_values.attribute_id = attributes.id AND attributes.name = 'length'
WHERE substring_index(attribute_values.value,'inch',1) + 0 BETWEEN 0 AND 5
```

Everything works fine however I am getting plenty of warnings:

```
Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'black'    
Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'phat farm'    
Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '2 kg'    
Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'roca wear'
```

it looks to me like that substring is going through all attribute_values in the database, even those that are not reffering to attribute 'length' - is it possible to change that ?

Comment: Yes there is no guarantee what expression is evaluated first between join and where. The substring index does also not get rid of inch, it just gives you its position.

Comment: First step of plan building is convert the JOIN query to cartesian + 5 conditions in WHERE (4 - from jois).

Comment: Clean up the data _before_ putting it into a table.